# Run Calculation, Copy and Paste Values VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to write this macro that will refresh the worksheet (Calculator)

And it refreshes, so it will take some values, copy them, and paste-special them in another sheet.

There are two Worksheets

1. Calculator
2. Iterations

There is my code:

```
Sub Iterate()

  Dim i As Integer

  For i = 1 To 10000
      Worksheets("Calculator").Calculate
      Range(AC6,AC16).Copy
      Range(AT10,AT11).Copy
      Worksheets("Iterations").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
  Next

     End Sub
```

I get an Error when I run this,

```
   Compile Error 
Expected: Identifier
```

I don't have a lot of experience with VBA.

The Calculator Worksheet makes a different calculation every refresh that will sum up to the Ranged Cells. 
I want to Copy those cells, and paste them in "Iteration" worksheet, one next to the other. 
What will eventually result in 10,000 copies

Any advice on where to start tackling it?

Comment: use "sub yourSubName() " at the beginning of  your code.

Comment: cells(1,1) should be numeric, use range("AC6:AC16), calculate should be sheets(1).calculate.

Comment: As mentioned, your `Cells()` references are incorrectly given too - while not the error you posted about, it would throw an error when you get to it. `Cells(#,#)` or `Range("A1")` is the typical format

Comment: how do I specify where do I want it pasted?

Comment: Also, why do you want to do this 10,000 times? Each time you do it, it's going to overwrite the values where you're pasting. You have a bunch of issues with the code, but can you explain more? Do you want the pasting on Iterations to change where the destination is, each iteration?

Comment: I assumed my code isn't close to be good. My experience with VBA is very little. 
I want it to paste it, and then move another column and paste the next one there. 

I want to do this 10,000 because I need 10,000 calculations of that spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Also your loop has no end.
You should define your loop for example like this:

```
For i=1 to 100000

'do something

Next
```

If You want to calculate your worksheet Calculator use:

```
Worksheets("Calculator").Calculate
```

I'm not sure what you want to copy (and where put it).

Comment: I want to copy, Range(AC6,AC16) and Range(AT10,AT11)

and put them in the Worksheets("Iterations")

Comment: I edited the code on the first question according to your suggestions

Comment: Ok. And destination range is the same, but in Iteration Worksheet? If so, there is no need to use loop, because you will write 10000 times the same value :)

Comment: The destination doesn't have to be the same in the Iteration worksheet, could basically begin from A1 and 10,000 after. 

I didn't entirely understand what you said about writing 10000 the value. 

and I guess that I didn't completely explain myself up there about what happens in general. 

but the moment the worksheet refreshes, excel makes calculations based on some N random numbers that sum of to these cells.. 

Thats why I want 10,000 of these, so I would have 10,000 possible option

Comment: Change it to what?